# Where are Model-Specific Registers (MSRs) physically located?

Tags: cpu-architecture, x86, intel, register

Specifically talking about Intel MSRs, where are they physically located in the computer ? Are they inside the CPU just like other general purpose registers? Are they mapped to RAM ?
To read/write an MSR I'm storing some addresses in ecx register. What these addresses correspond to ? Are these Physical Memory addresses ? If so can I just read the value of an MSR from RAM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those registers are located inside each CPU core (each core has its own set). They are not necessarily all in one place - they can be "sprinkled" around the core. MSRs that contain an address might be positioned close to the memory addressing unit. MSRs that enable instructions might be close to the instruction decoder, etc. Each MSR might have a direct internal connection to the unit it controls.

If an MSR has some reserved bits - those bits might not actually exist in hardware. Because those bits are always 0 - there is no need to store them. So, the hardware MSRs might be actually smaller than 64 bits.

MSRs are **not** mapped to RAM. The address in ECX has nothing to do with the memory addresses. They are just numbers, that identify each MSR. They are only valid for `rdmsr` and `wrmsr`.

Answer (score 0):

Think about MSR as a function where address supplied in ECX is MSR's name not address really.

Some MSRs are persistent i.e. act as a storage, some are not. They are like device (MMIO) registers rather than CPU general purpose registers and as such are subject for masking (reserved bits), access modes (like write 1 clears) and side-effects (same as CPU's control registers).

Same MSR might be shared by threads in the same core, cores in the same socket or among all sockets, such that if it's persistent then writing to its "address" on one core will make written value visible at other core even on other socket (if MSR is shared between sockets) - this is how "mailbox" MSRs work among cores.

In the extreme case, it could act as interface such that written value is parameter to some functionality attached to MSR's "address" (it's function not register, right?) and value consumed entirely and could not be read back (write-only mode).

So socket-shared MSR could be outside processor's core or even uncore, for instance, land in power management device. How exactly CPU's rdmsr/wrmsr API with number ("address") in ECX is transformed to the specific transaction depends on specific implementation (like access using primary vs sideband I/O bus interface with re-mapped addresses).

So MSR is a function with optional storage attached and accessed via RDMSR/WRMSR instructions by its number ("address").

Check "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 4: Model-Specific Register" for all the bloody-technical details.